# Converting access SQL to MYSQL, How to If(isnull(Max( a column on Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, max, isnull

beginner here. I'm converting Access sql to MYSQL so I can run bash files and I ran into this 1 issue where 3 days of web searching as lead me no where.

I have a table with two primary fields, "SalesOrderId" and "SOItemID" So the table may look like this:

```
+--------------+----------+--------+
| SalesOrderid | SOItemId | PartId |
+--------------+----------+--------+
|   10001      |     1    |  147   |
|   10002      |     1    |  152   |
|   10003      |     1    |  152   |
|   10003      |     2    |  188   |
|   10004      |     1    |  105   |
|   10004      |     2    |  84    |
|   10004      |     3    |  209   |
|   10005      |     1    |   5    |
+--------------+----------+--------+
```

On insert, i need to check if the SalesOrderId exists and if so, +1 the SOItemId field and insert the new record. If not then insert SOItemId as 1. So if I were to insert another PartId to SalesOrderId# 10004, it'd insert as `(10004, 4, 299)`  Here is the code in Access SQL that currently works.

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO SOItem ( SalesOrderId, SOItemId, PartId, CustDeliv, OnDate, Qty, UnitAmount, WebOrderProductId )
SELECT SalesOrder.SalesOrderId, If(IsNull(Max(`SOItemId`,"SOItem","SalesOrderId= " & [SalesOrderId] & " ")),1,DMax("[SOItemId]","SOItem","SalesOrderId= " & [SalesOrderId] & " ")+1) AS Expr1, ICS_Web_Parts_Link.PartId, SalesOrder.Date, SalesOrder.Date, order_product.quantity, order_product.price, order_product.order_product_id
FROM (order_product INNER JOIN ICS_Web_Parts_Link ON order_product.model = ICS_Web_Parts_Link.Model) INNER JOIN SalesOrder ON order_product.order_id = SalesOrder.WebOrderId;
```

Here's my MYSQL version:

```
INSERT INTO `SOItem` ( SalesOrderId, SOItemId, PartId, CustDeliv, OnDate, Qty, UnitAmount, WebOrderProductId )
SELECT `SalesOrder`.`SalesOrderId`, If(IsNull(Max(`SOItem`.`SOItemId`, `SOItemId`.`SalesOrderId` = `SalesOrder`.`SalesOrderId`)),1,Max(`SOItem`.`SOItemId`, `SOItemId`.`SalesOrderId` = SalesOrder`.`SalesOrderId`)+1) AS Expr1, ICS_Web_Parts_Link.PartId, SalesOrder.Date, SalesOrder.Date, order_product.quantity, order_product.price, order_product.order_product_id
FROM (order_product INNER JOIN ICS_Web_Parts_Link ON order_product.model = ICS_Web_Parts_Link.Model) INNER JOIN SalesOrder ON order_product.order_id = SalesOrder.WebOrderId;
```

I get this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `SOItemId`.`SalesOrderId` = `SalesOrder`.`SalesOrderId`)),1,Max(`SOItem`.`SOIte' at line 2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.      -Dan

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `SOItemId.SalesOrderId` implies that you're referencing a table called `SOItemId`, which has a column called `SalesOrderId`. That's clearly not what you're doing (there's no table with that name, at least not joined to this query), so that's why it's throwing a syntax error at you.

It's not clear exactly what you are trying to join to what. I suggest you spend some more time looking at SQL exercises and examples of working code. While you're at it, make sure you understand how `MAX` and `ISNULL` work in MySQL. (Consider using `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this in MySQL.  This is just an example using what you referenced above but you can execute it as-is to see how it works and then apply it to your use-case.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales_test;

CREATE TABLE `sales_test` (
  `SalesOrderid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SOItemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SalesOrderid, SOItemId),
  UNIQUE KEY `SalesOrderid` (`SalesOrderid`,`SOItemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO sales_test (SalesOrderid, SOItemId, PartId) VALUES 
(10001, 1, 147),
(10002, 1, 152),
(10003, 1, 152),
(10003, 2, 188),
(10004, 1, 105),
(10004, 2, 84),
(10004, 3, 209),
(10005, 1, 5);

SELECT * FROM sales_test;

INSERT INTO sales_test (SalesOrderid, SOItemId, PartId) 
VALUES (10005, 1, 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SOItemId = SOItemId + 1;

SELECT * FROM sales_test;
```

Comment: I now realize my question wasn't completely clear and this solution would have worked for what I was asking.. This updated the existing record to `(10005, 2, 5)`. I edited my original post to reflect what I really wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out. Thanks for all your help!
To anybody with the same problem, here is the mysql code that works.

```
INSERT INTO `SOItem` ( SalesOrderId, SOItemId, PartId, CustDeliv, OnDate, Qty, UnitAmount, WebOrderProductId )
SELECT `SalesOrder`.`SalesOrderId`, IF((SELECT (SOItem.SOItemId) FROM d1.SOItem WHERE SalesOrder.SalesOrderId = SOItem.SalesOrderId) IS NULL, 1, (SELECT MAX(SOItem.SOItemId)+1 FROM d1.SOItem WHERE SalesOrder.SalesOrderId = SOItem.SalesOrderId)) AS Expr1, ICS_Web_Parts_Link.PartId, SalesOrder.Date, SalesOrder.Date, order_product.quantity, order_product.price, order_product.order_product_id
FROM d2.order_product INNER JOIN d1.ICS_Web_Parts_Link ON order_product.model = ICS_Web_Parts_Link.Model INNER JOIN d1.SalesOrder ON order_product.order_id = SalesOrder.WebOrderId LEFT JOIN d1.SOItem ON order_product.order_product_id = SOItem.WebOrderProductId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT order_product_id FROM d2.order_product WHERE order_product.order_product_id = SOItem.WebOrderProductId);
```

Comment: There is a better way to do this if you have permission to change the tables key structure. Is that an option for you? If so I can post an example.

Comment: I do have full permissions and I'm always open to improvement!